# cURL/wget - SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT hangs

Tags: curl, ssl, https

I have problems connecting to https sites using cURL or wget. When I download from a https curl seems to be stuck while doing the TLS handshake, CERT.
The problem is independent of the site (I noticed it using github) and wget is hanging too (although I didn't look into the verbose outputs there).

```
$ curl -v --trace-time https://www.google.de
10:35:21.532822 * About to connect() to www.google.de port 443 (#0)
10:35:21.533091 *   Trying 209.85.148.147... connected
10:35:21.538666 * Connected to www.google.de (209.85.148.147) port 443 (#0)
10:35:21.539119 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
10:35:21.544129 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
10:35:21.544182 * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
```

I have waited >10 min but nothing happens. I am using OSX Lion.

```
$curl --version
curl 7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I don't know where to look for help so I'd be happy if you could give me some pointers.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other HTTPS sites? Do you have the same problem with other HTTPS clients? Are you behind a firewall that might inspect or hijack SSL traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> curl -v --trace-time https://www.google.de

```
21:50:34.054955 * About to connect() to www.google.de port 443
21:50:34.056574 *   Trying 74.125.39.104... connected
21:50:34.104587 * Connected to www.google.de (74.125.39.104) port 443
21:50:34.313259 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
21:50:34.313349 *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
21:50:34.313758 * SSLv2, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSL connection using RC4-SHA
21:50:34.418541 * Server certificate:
21:50:34.418631 *        subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
21:50:34.418726 *        start date: 2011-10-26 00:00:00 GMT
21:50:34.418799 *        expire date: 2013-09-30 23:59:59 GMT
21:50:34.418902 * SSL: certificate subject name 'www.google.com' does not match target host name 'www.google.de'
21:50:34.419000 * Closing connection #0
21:50:34.419124 * SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name 'www.google.com' does not match target host name 'www.google.de'
```

It seems you are not able to verify the certificate since you are missing the ca-bundle.crt. This belongs (in CentOS 5) to the openssl-rpm.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to manage these things in Mac OS X / Darwin would be to install a packagemanager such as Homebrew (http://brew.sh/)

This way when you install software like cURL you would get the whole dependency list too or you can just `brew install openssl` and problem solved ;)

Comment: Note to the reviewers: link is clean, contains real software which is important part of the answer.

Comment: I am already using Homebrew. Thanks for the tip though.